# Return the character associated with the specified Ascii code in R

Tags: r, character, ascii

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create a cartesian product in R with the letters of the alphabet.

What I'm actually trying is this:

First I create a matrix with the letters

```
a <- as.matrix(seq(97,122,by=1))
```

Then I create a data frame with 2 columns with all the combinations

```
b <- expand.grid(a, a)
```

Finally I combine the 2 columns

```
apply(b,1,paste,collapse=" ")
```

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to transform those "decimals" to its Ascii character.

I have tried several things like rawToChar and gsub unsuccessfully.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you directly use `letters`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First direct method:

```
res <- do.call(paste, expand.grid(letters, letters))
```

If you've some other ascii values and you want to get equivalent characters:

```
val <- 65:96 # whatever values you want the equivalent characters for
mode(val) <- "raw" # set mode to raw
# alternatively, val <- as.raw(65:96)
a   <- sapply(val, rawToChar)
res <- do.call(paste, expand.grid(a, a))
```

Comment: Try to avoid calling a variable `c` though.

Answer (score 30):

A very easy way to return a character based on its ASCII code is the function `intToUtf8`. It also works for vectors including multiple integers and returns the corresponding characters as one string.

```
vec <- 97:122
intToUtf8(vec)
# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

intToUtf8(65)
# [1] "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

To print an ASCII char in R you can use the `print` function with a backslash `\` before an ASCII code number.  For example to print the character equivalent of 150 use `print("\150")`.

Or for your example above you could try:

```
a <- sapply(97:122,function(x) rawToChar(as.raw(x)))

b <- expand.grid(a,a)

c <- t(apply(b,1,function(x) paste(x[1],x[2])))
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. No, what I need is to "Replace" the numeric values in a data frame to their corresponding letters, for using them inside the code. Thanks again.

Comment: I agree with @Arun it's probably easier to just use `letters`, but I'll update my example with what you said.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I have tried that, but it doesn't do what I need. It returns 2 variables but not the cartesian product of them.